# PHP / MySQL Connection issues. Parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, connection

Getting these errors when attempting to post stuff to a database from a form:

```
Notice: Undefined index: formUser in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Crewniverse/index.php on line 49

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Crewniverse/index.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: formPass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Crewniverse/index.php on line 50

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Crewniverse/index.php on line 50
```

Code is:

```
<?php
$dbServer = "localhost";
$db = "Crewniverse";
$dbUser = "url_acc";
$dbPassword = "url_pass";


$db_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "url_acc", "url_pass", "Crewniverse");
//evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    die("<br>Couldn't connect!");
}

$formUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['formUser']);
$formPass=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['formPass']);


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO username_pass (formUser, formPass)VALUES('$formUser', '$formPass')";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('error Updating database');
}

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: STOP right now, and use `mysqli_()` or `PDO`, **`mysql_()` is now deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters
```

Look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

```
$formUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,$_POST['formUser']);
$formPass=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,$_POST['formPass']);
```

And it is `deprecated`

Comment: this + isset() to avoid the "not set" notices.

Comment: I don't understand what parameters I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

use [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to avoid notices like below
and also you miss parameter in [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

```
$frmuser = (isset($_POST['formUser']) ? $_POST['formUser'] : '');
$formPass= (isset($_POST['formPass']) ? $_POST['formPass'] : '');

$formUser=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,$frmuser);
$formPass=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,$formPass);
```

and also use `mysqli_query()` instaed of `mysql_query()`